# How can I use image files as <img> source using Rollup as bundler?

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I my source code, this import path is correct:

```
<img src={"../../../../assets/logo.svg"} />
```

But the relative path changes during the bundling process. How can I make the code to continue to work after bundling?

I think that if my project was plain JS I could use `@rollup/plugin-image`. But I haven't gotten it to work in my Typescript project.

When I try to use it as described in the docs I get the following error in my project:

```
Cannot find module '../../../../assets/logo.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Reading a few other threads on this topic, I have tried to fix this problem by adding a `types.d.ts` file to my project:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

But the hasn't made a difference. The TypeScript error remains.

EDIT:

Adding some information

**rollup.config.js**

```
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";

const pkg = require("./app/package.json");

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development";

export default [
  {
    input: "./src/renderer/renderer.tsx",
    output: [{ dir: "./app/build", format: "es", sourcemap: isProd ? false : true }],
    plugins: [
      typescript({ tsconfig: isProd ? "./tsconfig.prod.json" : "./tsconfig.dev.json" }),
      resolve({
        mainFields: ["module", "main", "jsnext:main", "browser"],
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      }),
      commonjs(),
      replace({
        "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        // Gets rid of console warning to install React Dev Tools for a better development experience
        __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__: "({ isDisabled: true })",
      }),
      isProd && terser(),
      copy({
        targets: [
          {
            src: ["./src/renderer/index.html", "./src/renderer/styles.css"],
            dest: "./app/build",
          },
        ],
      }),
      image(),
    ],
  },
];
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Output
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNEXT",
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmit": true,
    // Compile time code checking
    "strict": true,
    // Libraries
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    // Imports
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", "app"]
}
```

**types.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import logo from "../../../../assets/logo.svg";
// Cannot find module '../../../../assets/logo.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Comment: Could you please recreate a minimal reproductible example using [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) please?